# Use non-breaking space in Symfony translation

Tags: symfony, translation

I am trying to use a non-breaking space character &nbsp; in a translation.

```
# messages.cs.yml
"City near river": "Město u&nbsp;řeky"
```

However, the non-breaking space character is escaped when translating in template.

```
{{ 'City near river'|trans }} # prints "Město u&amp;nbsp;řeky"
```

Is there any way how to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

You may try to add [`raw` filter](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html) like:

```
{{ 'City near river'|trans|raw }}
```

This will prevent Twig from automatic escaping.

Also I think that it would be better to prevent breaking string in CSS instead of putting a `&nbsp;` there.

You can achieve that with CSS rule:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

assigned to the element containing translated string.

This way you will get more flexible translations as you may not want to get this html entity every time you use this string.

Comment: I cannot use white-space:nowrap because I want the text to break normally. I only need non-breaking space after single character prepositions, like "u" or "v". It's a specific language grammer (Czech).

Comment: Using raw filter might work but this would break the HTML if the translation was for example "Mike & Co" => "&" would not be escaped here. I finally found a solution using a unicode char, see my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

I just found a solution using Unicode character:

```
# messages.cs.yml
"City near river": "Město u\xA0řeky"
```